# How do I add a time difference to an array with PHP?

Tags: php

I have the following array structure in MySQL. There could be no items or many items; the example shows only three.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            ...
            [start_time] => 09:00:00
            [finish_time] => 10:20:00
            ...
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            ...
            [start_time] => 13:00:00
            [finish_time] => 14:20:00
            ...
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 23
            ...
            [start_time] => 18:05:00
            [finish_time] => 19:35:00
            ...
        )

     etc etc

)
```

I want to add the time difference between start_time and finish_time and find out the total time with PHP.

For example, the above should produce 250min or 4 hr 10min (80 min + 80min + 90min). How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PHP:

```
$total_diff = 0;

foreach($items as $item)
{
    $total_diff += strtotime($item['finish_time']) - strtotime($item['start_time']);
}
```

The [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function will convert the time value to seconds. You can then convert the `$total_diff` value to minutes, hours, etc as required.

If you have access to modify the original MySQL query, you could do it in a single query:

```
SELECT sum( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(finish_time) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_time) )
FROM table
```

In the above, [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) performs the same function as strtotime() in PHP.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

        $arr = array(  0 => Array
                (
                        'start_time' => '09:00:00',
                        'finish_time' => '10:20:00'
                ),

                1 => Array
                (

                        'start_time' => '13:00:00',
                        'finish_time' => '14:20:00'
                ),
                2 => Array
                (

                        'start_time' => '18:05:00',
                        'finish_time' => '19:35:00'


                )
        );
        $accumulator = 0;
        foreach($arr as $entry) {
            $accumulator += strtotime($entry['finish_time']) - strtotime($entry['start_time']);
        }
        $hours = floor($accumulator / 3600);
        $mins = ($accumulator-$hours*3600)/60;
        echo "$hours:$mins";
        ?>
```

this is my output:

`4:10`

Answer (score 1):

If you are lucky enough to be using PHP version 5.3, this version comes with a built-in [date/time diff function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php). The examples on the manual page are quite simple to follow.

I dislike using the strtotime() function as per the other answers because it has some unexpected quirks (mainly when dealing with date formats), and also because it's quite a processor-heavy function for simple usage like this - it's a bit of a sledgehammer to crack a nut. However if you're on PHP 5.2 or earlier, it is probably your best bet.

If you are getting the time data from a database, you could also use MySQL to calculate the diff, or at least to give you the results in an integer format which will make it easier to work with. (then you could just do a simple subtraction to get the difference in seconds)

Hope that helps.